# Rspec testing: `eql?` matcher failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am having trouble while writing specs:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(Question.all.count).to eql(0)

       expected: 0
            got: 0.0

       (compared using eql?)
```

Why is `count` returning a float value, and even if it had not, wouldn't the expectation be `true`?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why `Question.all.count` returns `0.0`, but the matcher is working as expected. According to the [documentation](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-3/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers):

```
expect(a).to equal(b) # passes if a.equal?(b)
expect(a).to eql(b)   # passes if a.eql?(b)
expect(a).to be == b  # passes if a == b
```

In your case `expect(0.0).to eql(0)` invokes:

```
0.0.eql?(0) #=> false
```

It returns `fase` because that's how [`Float#eql?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Float.html#method-i-eql-3F) works:

> Returns true only if `obj` is a `Float` with the same value as `float`. Contrast this with [`Float#==`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Float.html#method-i-3D-3D), which performs type conversions.

To compare with `a == b` you would use:

```
expect(Question.all.count).to be == 0
```

or

```
expect(Question.all.count).to eq(0)
```