# I can't get my Fibonacci sequence to pass this rspec test in Ruby. How do I go about it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I was given a test to pass on Fibonacci sequence in Ruby and I've been searching for an answer ever since. I couldn't come up with anything satisfactory and the 'closest' I've got to solving it is (after seeing something on Fibonacci on SO):

```
class Fibonacci

def generate( n )
  return  n  if (0..1).include? n
  ( fibonacci( n - 1 ) + fibonacci( n - 2 ) )
end
```

This is the test:

```
describe "Fibonacci" do
  it "can output the fibonacci sequence for 5 numbers" do
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(5)).to eql([0,1,1,2,3])
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(5).last).to eql(3)
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(5)[-2]).to eql(2)
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(5)[2]).to eql(1)
  end

  it "can output the fibonacci sequence for 20 numbers" do
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(20)).to eql([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181])
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(20).last).to eql(4181)
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(20)[-2]).to eql(2584)
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(20)[5]).to eql(5)
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(20)[6]).to eql(8)
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(20)[7]).to eql(13)
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(20)[-3]).to eql(1597)
  end

  it "can output the fibonacci sequence for 50 numbers" do
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(50)).to eql([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 4807526976, 7778742049])
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(50).last).to eql(7778742049)
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(50).count).to eql(50)
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(50)[24]).to eql(46368)
    expect(Fibonacci.generate(50)[12]).to eql(144)
  end
end
```

What do I change to make it satisfy the test?

Comment: first you explain **HOW** this code isn't working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the documentation about formatting text in questions. As is, it's very difficult to read your question, making it more difficult and slower for us to help you.

Comment: Please improve the code formatting of your question to simplify the reading.

Comment: I don't know. I'm totally new to this. If this isn't supposed to be here, is there a site for total beginners, please?

Comment: The tests probably are all failing. look what kind of thing the test expect, look what kind of thing your method is returning. Explain it to us. There is no use when somebody gives the solution, as you will not learn anything.

Comment: You should at least provide the error or failure message to give us something to work with

Comment: Oh Documentation How I Love Thee. Check out [`Enumerator::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-new) this is the best way to build a Fibonacci Sequence in my opinion.

Comment: Also you should use `eq` instead of `eql`, neighbor question explains why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32523074/rspec-testing-eql-matcher-failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generate` method you have is an instance method, but your tests are testing for a class method. To make the method into a class method in Ruby use the `self` keyword in the method signature like this:

```
def self.generate(n)
```

or use the class name in the signature like this:

```
def Fibonacci.generate(n)
```

Also the tests themselves mostly aren't useful and need rewriting.